# Wordpress Site Moving error Fatal error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my local system i installed sparkling theme in wordpress and created child theme . This was working Fine.After i completing my works i moved files into server .Updated wp-config files and updated siteurl,home in wp_options table.But this not works.Gives error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function sparkling_header_menu() ".Please Help

Comment: disable one by one plugin and check it

Comment: Can you log in into admincenter? Change your theme in default and than try again to use your sparkling theme.

Comment: Not able to login into admin dashboard.This also gives error

Comment: make sure you uploaded all the files correctly, that function seems to belong to the theme you mention.

Comment: Do you have some inlcudes() included?

Comment: Yes files uploaded correctly.But not works

Comment: @cgee where i can check that

Comment: Check you childtheme which you created.. Maybe there is somewhere in the header a wrong url.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: my problem is database size is more than 1GB and php.ini max file size set but i also have problem here.check plugin folders one by one by cpanel and replace theme but error still here. check permission to wp db and username and password but still problem here. check htaccess file but still have that error message

Answer (score 0):

To get your site back up and running delete both the child theme directory and the sparkle theme. That will get your site backup and running.

Also make sure you have one of the WordPress standard themes uploaded.